# What happens when you call glClearColor with a negative argument?

Tags: c, opengl, colors

I'm working on a simple OpenGL application that allows the user to adjust the background color of a simple window by clicking and dragging to either then left (make it less intense) or the right (more intense). When dragging to the right, for example, I have something like this:

```
intensity += 0.0001*x;  //where x is the current mouse location
```

...and to the left, the other way:

```
intensity -= 0.0001*x;
```

`intensity` is global static GLfloat that gets passed to `glClearColor` in the display function, which is called multiple times. This strategy works just fine when the user intensifies the color while dragging right, but it messes up after a certain point when dragging left: the color becomes less intense as I drag along and returns to black as it should, but then intensifies back into the original color.

I think the problem is that the intensity, which should be between 0 and 1, is becoming negative when I drag too far and, thus, `glClearColor` is fixing the problem by just changing the sign back to positive (?). If that is the case, how can I enforce that the values passed to `glClearColor` stay in the proper range? I tried to fix the problem by making sure that the current intensity would not become negative/adjustment would not happen if it is already too low, but it didn't seem to work:

```
if(x <= xPrev && intensity >= (.0001*x))  //moving left to de-intensify color
  intensity -= 0.0001*x;
```

...Am I doing this incorrectly, or is `glClearColor` handling negative values differently than I expect?

Another interesting issue that came up is that my "intensity" adjustments only seem to work on the r, g, and/or b values (i.e., I pass "intensity" as one of those in `glClearColor`. Using the a value didn't work...but isn't it supposed to change color intensity?

Comment: "*how can I enforce that the values passed to glClearColor stay in the proper range?*" You... you don't know how to clamp a floating-point value? Why don't you try doing that, and tell us whether this fixes your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds a bit like a [hysteresis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis#User_interface_design) problem. It's not clear how events are received, or what coordinate system `x` is in. Perhaps drop an 'anchor' (`xStart`) when the button is pressed, and handle all subsequent values while dragging as an offset from this value. What toolkit / library are you using for windows and events? If you launch from a console, perhaps add a trace statements like:

`fprintf(stderr, "%.8e\n", x);`

to see if the values of `x` correspond to what you're expecting on each frame.

[glClearColor](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glClearColor.xml) clamps values to `[0, 1]`, so it's probably not the issue. Perhaps a trace for `intensity` would be useful?

Comment: "*glClearColor clamps values to [0, 1]*" [No, it doesn't](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glClearColor) (I *really* wish OpenGL.org would take down those old, outdated and dangerously buggy pages). As of 4.3, `glClearColor` takes `GLfloat`s, but even before that, the specification clearly stated that the color was *only* clamped if a normalized integer buffer were being cleared.

Comment: Interesting. I've never been in a situation where I would pass a negative value to `glClearColor`. OTOH, `glClearColor` isn't specified with `GLclampf` anymore.

Comment: Whether or not glClearColor clamps anything, I'm wondering what it's doing to my values. I can probably do some tests with output, but I wish the gl online resources were more clear about this. I'm using GLUT, by they way.

Comment: @nicole: The resources *are* clear about this. The spec is very clear: if the color buffer being cleared is a normalized integer buffer, then the float value passed in will be clamped.

Comment: Which means, for example, that "-0.8" becomes what? "0.8?"